# what is this set

Tags: real-analysis

While trying previous year exam question paper of real analysis i got struck on this particular question and so I am posting here for help.

> Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a linear map $f(0,0,\dots)=0$. Then the set $\{f(x_{1},...,x_{n} ):\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j}^2\leq 1\}$ equals

A. $[-a,a]$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\geq 0 $.

B. $[0,1]$

C. $[0,a]$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\geq 0 $.

D. $[a,b]$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $0\leq a<b $.

I have no idea on how this set will be and so i am sorry bt i have nothing which i can show as an attempt.

I request you to tell in which direction I should proceed .

Comment: Well, work some examples.  Maybe start with $n=1$.

Comment: It is the image of the unit ball by a linear map L, i.e. an (hyper) ellipsoid in general; particular cases when range(L) is not $\mathbb{R}^n$ : the hyperboloid is degenerated (for example if $n=2$, instead of an ellipse, one can get for example a line segment...

Comment: If you only have to give an answer, not a proof, you can easily get an example where the result is negative, so you can rule out B, C, and D.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(-x)=-f(x).\,\,\,\,\,$